# what does this iptables chain rule do?

Tags: linux, iptables

What does this iptables command do and why do we use `-m state` and what does it means ?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-m <module>` means that you want to give that rule access to whatever the  module defines, in case of the state module, that is mainly the `--state` matching.

This rule matches all traffic that is either part of an `ESTABLISHED` connection or `RELATED` to an established connection (e.g. ftp makes extra connections, those are related to an established connection).